# Startup redmine 1.2 fail

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine

When I try to startup the redmine 1.2 with the server which binding with redmine itself, but it show me an error of gem,  info like below:

```
[root@XPG redmine-1.2.0]# ruby script/server webtrick -e production
Missing the i18n 0.4.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n`
```

even if I have installed the gem it said:

```
[root@XPG redmine-1.2.0]# gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aasm (2.2.0)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
arel (2.0.10)
Ascii85 (1.0.1)
block_helpers (0.3.3)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.14)
capybara (1.0.0)
childprocess (0.1.9)
cucumber (1.0.0)
cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
edavis10-object_daddy (0.4.3)
erubis (2.6.6)
ffi (1.0.9)
gherkin (2.4.1)
holidays (1.0.2)
i18n (0.4.2)
icalendar (1.1.6)
json (1.6.1, 1.5.3)
json_pure (1.5.3)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mocha (0.9.12)
mysql (2.8.1)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
pdf-reader (0.9.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
prawn (0.11.1)
rack (1.2.3, 1.1.2, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.0)
rubygems-update (1.8.11, 1.8.4, 1.5.3, 1.3.7)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
selenium-webdriver (0.2.2)
shoulda (2.10.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
ttfunk (1.0.1)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

But the issue is still appeared, is there any idea to fix it?

Comment: It's possibly that the gem is not properly installed.  Try uninstalling and re-installing it.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I see, your command is not correct.

1. server's name is webrick, not "webtrick"
2. even using webrick, it doesn't support production environment.
3. seems that you are not using rails3/bundler

I suggest that you start the webserver using either mongrel or thin, both of them are faster and stabler than webrick.

Comment: Thanks Siwei, yes, this is a server for running the redmine only, the rails is installed, as you see below:[root@XPG redmine-1.2.0]# /usr/local/bin/rails -v
Rails 2.3.5, adn I did the step 1 and 2 as you said, but the issue is still appeared, do you have any other idea?

Comment: from this guide:  http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall , it requires rubygem < 1.6, however I noticed that your rubygem has an version of 1.8.x. please show me your result of this command: `$ gem env`.